# JavaScript: Проверка CSS стиля и переключение его по клику на ссылку

Tags: javascript, html, css

Доброго времени суток. Прошу помощи с js.
Есть код:

```
<a class="default">111</a>
<a class="red">222</a>
<a class="default">333</a>  
<a class="default">444</a>  
<a class="red">555</a>
```

Есть два стиля:

```
.default{
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    color:gray;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
    color: blue;
}
```

Необходимо при клике на ссылку применять ей противоположный стиль css, то есть, если у ссылки задан стиль "default", то при клике заменить его на "red" и наоборот.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы используете jQuery, то вот такой код может подойти

```
$('a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // что бы не было перехода по ссылке
    $(this).toggleClass('default red');
})
```